# How to change delimiter from comma to # in a csv using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Can the delimiter be changed from comma to # while exporting records to csv file.

In the below example

```
mongoexport -d mydb -c coll --csv --fields "ProductId,ModerationStatus,Rating,TotalCommentCount" --out results.csv
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid there's no option to change the delimiter when using mongoexport.

Comment: You cannot change this using mongoexport, but since it is a csv file you can do a replaceAll "," -> "#" in a text editor.

Comment: The problem is one of the fields ModerationStatus contains array of values which are comma separated. Even that value will be replaced with #.

Comment: There is currently an open issue to add this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-87

Answer (score 5):

Currently, mongoexport does not have this feature.

However, you can develop a simple JavaScript for doing this. So you have the control over the format of csv and field data types.

**export.js**

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("myDB");
var cur = db.myCollection.find();

var obj;
while(cur.hasNext()){
    obj = cur.next();
    print("\""+obj._id+"\";\""+obj.field_1+"\";\""+obj.field_2+"\"");
}
```

Call this script from your OS shell:

```
mongo --quiet export.js > file_name.csv
```

**--quiet:** disables Mongo default option to print "version", "connecting to", etc, therefore the output of the script will be just things printed explicitly using print()

Comment: it's work with custom like this, but in the file exported show this on the top. MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10

Answer (score 0):

not a very clean solution but you can build a your own version of mongoexport adding inside the code "Comma" statement

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/master/mongoexport/csv.go

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer

```
// WriteHeader writes a comma-delimited list of fields as the output header row.
func (csvExporter *CSVExportOutput) WriteHeader() error {
    if !csvExporter.NoHeaderLine {

        //here the trick
        csvExporter.csvWriter.Comma = '|'
        //

        csvExporter.csvWriter.Write(csvExporter.Fields)
        return csvExporter.csvWriter.Error()
    }
    return nil
}
```